How to Display Large PDF Files in Streamlit Using Base64 Encoding
I am working on a Python project where I need to display PDF files in a dialog box using Streamlit. To do this, I convert the PDF files into base64 binary format. The code works fine for PDF files smaller than 2MB, but I encounter issues with larger files. When I try to display PDF files larger than 2MB, they don't open in the Streamlit dialog box, even though smaller files work perfectly.
Here is the code snippet I am using:
import streamlit as st
import os
import base64

@st.experimental_dialog("PDF File Vieweer",width="large")
def show_pdf(item):
    st.markdown(item,unsafe_allow_html=True)

def view_file(file_path):
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1].lower()
    
    if file_extension == '.pdf':
        with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
            base64_pdf = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
        
        pdf_link=f'<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_pdf}" height=1000 width="100%"></iframe>'

        show_pdf(pdf_link)

current_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
document_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, "Document")
pdf_file_path = os.path.join(document_directory,"RAG Research.pdf")

if st.button("View PDF"):
    view_file(pdf_file_path)

I've tried several approaches to troubleshoot the issue but haven't been successful. I'm unsure whether this problem is due to Streamlit's limitations, the method of encoding the PDF, or something else entirely.

Do not use image in question. instead add text to improve question quality.

Seems to be a known issue in Streamlist with suggestions to either embed in an iframe or split the pdf file. See https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/7444, https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/embed-pdf-files-that-are-larger-than-2mb/17264/5 and https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/looking-for-a-solution-to-embed-pdf-files-larger-than-1-5mb-without-splitting/66066

@Alexander -  did you get any solution for this?
